# Why i'm getting error while install axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

**package.json file**
[package.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0b5vy.png)
I have run this command

```
npm install axios
```

[This is the error that I'm getting while installing axios](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwxLS.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems there are some version conflicts in the packages
it's better to fix conflicts but if it doesn't matter and does not make any problem, you can install it using

> npm install axios --force

Comment: Hi Ali, Thanks for the help error is resolved now :-) 

Comment: happy to hear that, if my answer is correct please vote up and mark it as the answer @ShubhamNigam